# Populate multiple choice grid from sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, grid, google-forms

thanks to all, in advance, for any support you might be able to provide!
I'm trying to populate a Multiple Choice Grid in Google Forms from Google Sheets.
I've been able to populate dropdowns, but not grids.
Here is the code I'm using for a grid:

```
 var form = FormApp.openById("MyId");
    var GridList = form.getItemById("MyItem").asGridItem();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyGoogleSheet");
    var names = ss.getSheetByName("MySheet");
    var sheetValues = names.setRows(['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3'])
    var sheetValues = names.setColumns(['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
    var formValues = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++)    
    if(sheetValues[i][0] != "")
    formValues[i] = sheetValues[i][0];
    GridList.setChoiceValues(formValues);
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: There is no setColumns or setRows methods in Class Sheet.  You have two declarations for sheetValues neither of which make sense.  There's a lot of examples on SO to get data out of spreadsheets.  Do some more research.

Comment: How unkind and rude. In any case, I troubleshooted it and solved it, no thanks to you, Cooper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:
This populates rows and columns in a Multiple Choice Grid form question.

```
var form = FormApp.openById('MyId');
var PtjGridList = form.getItemById(MyItem).asGridItem();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyGoogleSheet");
var PtjNombre = ss.getSheetByName("MySheet");
var RowValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 5, PtjNombre.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
var ValuesRow = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++)
if(RowValues[i][0] != "")
ValuesRow[i] = RowValues[i][0];
PtjGridList.setRows(ValuesRow)
var ColumnValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 6, PtjNombre.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
var ValuesColumn = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++)
if(ColumnValues[i][0] != "")
ValuesColumn[i] = ColumnValues[i][0];
PtjGridList.setColumns(ValuesColumn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a few recommendations for you regarding your answer:

```
function afunc() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('MyId');
  var PtjGridList = form.getItemById(MyItem).asGridItem();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyGoogleSheet");
  var PtjNombre = ss.getSheetByName("MySheet");
  //var RowValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 5, PtjNombre.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
```

The above line should be replaced with the one below and your code will run faster and be more reliable.

```
  var RowValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 5, PtjNombre.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();//replace with this

  var ValuesRow = [];

  //sheetValues is undefined within this function
  for(var i = 0; i<sheetValues.length; i++)
    if(RowValues[i][0] != "")ValuesRow[i] = RowValues[i][0];
```

It would be better to rewrite the above function in the following way:

```
  for(var i = 0; i<sheetValues.length; i++) {
    if(RowValues[i][0] != "") {
      ValuesRow[i] = RowValues[i][0];
    }
  }
  PtjGridList.setRows(ValuesRow)
  //var ColumnValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 6, PtjNombre.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
```

Using getLastRow() is much better since using getMaxRows() can result in getting a lot of null values at the end of your data and often will result in errors.

```
  var ColumnValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 6, PtjNombre.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();//replace with this

  var ValuesColumn = [];

  //again sheetValues is not defined within this function
  for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++)
    if(ColumnValues[i][0] != "")
      ValuesColumn[i] = ColumnValues[i][0];
  //would be better to write like this:
```

Again sheetValues is not defined in this function and the following rewrite would improve readability greatly.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++) {
    if(ColumnValues[i][0] != "") {      
      ValuesColumn[i] = ColumnValues[i][0];
    }
  }

  PtjGridList.setColumns(ValuesColumn)
}
```

[getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

[getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)

I was not trying to  be  rude or unkind.  Your previous code had some serious problems and you addressed them and got it to run.  That's what we like to see. Good work.

Comment: Thank you. As in everything, form and content count. I will do my best to make the best use of your suggestions.